# Define field with FPAT

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to split data into field in awk, but I cant come up with the right regex using FPAT.

I have tried:

```
echo 'C002     2019-06-28;16:03;approved;content=L1-34,EE;not     taken;;1024 ' | awk 'BEGIN {FPAT = "([^ ]+) +[^ ]+|;"} {print "f1:"$1;print "f2:"$2;print "f3:"$3;print "f6:"$6;print "f7:"$7}'
```

Expected result:

```
f1:C002
f2:2019-06-28
f3:16:03
f6:not     taken
f7:
```

Comment: There isn't a clean way to split `"C002     2019-06-28"` on `' '` but not `"not    taken"`. Better to use a field separator of `';'` and then split field-1 on `' '`.

Comment: You have same number of spaces between `C002     2019-06-28;16:03`  and in `not     taken` but expect different behaviors?

Comment: @Inian Number of spaces is not constant

Comment: So how do you justify such a split? How to identify one case has to be split and other not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no simple way to separate random space from random space.
You need to do as David writes, separate using `;` and then split first field by space.

```
awk -F";" '{split($1,a,"[ \t]+");print "a[1]---"a[1]"\na[2]---"a[2];for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print i"---"$i}'
a[1]---C002
a[2]---2019-06-28
1---C002     2019-06-28
2---16:03
3---approved
4---content=L1-34,EE
5---not     taken
6---
7---1024
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit similar to the answer of Jotne, but you could write a function to split the record according to your wishes:

```
awk 'function split_record(string,f,   t,n,m) {
        n=split(string,t,";"); m=split(t[1],f,"[ \t]+")
        for(i=2;i<=n;++i) f[m+i-1]=t[i]
        return m+n-1
     }
     { split_record($0,f) }
     {print "f1:"f[1];print "f2:"f[2];print "f3:"f[3];print "f6:"f[6];print "f7:"f[7]}'
```

This returns:

```
f1:C002
f2:2019-06-28
f3:16:03
f6:not     taken
f7:
```

You can update the split record in any way you like.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS=";" }
    {
        split($1,a,/[[:space:]]+/)
        $1 = ""
        $0 = a[1] FS a[2] $0
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
            print "f" i ":" $i
        }
    }
' file
f1:C002
f2:2019-06-28
f3:16:03
f4:approved
f5:content=L1-34,EE
f6:not     taken
f7:
f8:1024
```